# Open divs using jquery, with the correct data

Tags: jquery, html

I am doing a **comment system** for my webpage.

The website shows a group of elements from the database, that everyone can comment:

Element 1 ($element_id=1)-> Read comments...

Element 2 ($element_id=2)-> Read comments...

Element 3 ($element_id=3)-> Read comments...

When someone want to read comments of one element, can click in the "Read comments...", and a new div opens:

```
<div class="comments_more" id="comments_more"> Read comments...
<div class="comments_div" id="comments_div" > 
<?php include/comments.php ?>
<?php echo $element_id; ?>
</div> </div>
```

The jquery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( '.comments_more' ).click(function() {
    $( '#comments_div' ).show('slide');
    });
    })
```

My problem is to show the div with the correct $post_id.
...because when we I click for example "Read comments..." in element 2, 3, etc, the comments_div always shows $element_id=1.

Comment: you try to use `this`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)/[`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to target the child `comments_div` of current element i.e. `this`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comments_more').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.comments_div').show('slide');
    });
})
```

Note: *Identifiers in HTML must be unique*.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML create data attribute. Like so:

```
<a href="#" class="comments_more" data-id="5"> Click </a>
```

Div to show:

```
<div class="comments_show_<?php echo $element_id; ?>">

   </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( '.comments_more' ).click(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

      $('.comments_show_' + id).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: could also be one line `$('.comments_show_' + $(this).data('id')).show("slide");`, if the OP wants to use the data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="comments_more"> Read comments...
    <div class="comments_div"> 
         <div class="comments">
             first comments
         </div>
         <div class="comments">
             second comments
         </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="comments_more"> Read comments...
    <div class="comments_div"> 
         <div class="comments">
             first comments
         </div>
         <div class="comments">
             second comments
         </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Assume the above structure for the comments.  Note that the ID must be unique on the page so I removed that attribute and just use classes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comments_more').on('click',function() {
        $(this).find('.comments_div').show('slide');
    });
});
```

It would not matter if the "comments" were interspersed with other html (like the article etc. like so:

```
<div class="article"> myarticle stuff
</div>
<div class="comments_more"> Read comments...
  . . . the comments as above
</div>
<div class="article"> new stuff
</div>
<div class="comments_more"> Read comments...
  . . . the comments as above
</div>
```

If you only wanted ONE comment open you could close others first:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comments_more').on('click',function() {
        $('.comments_more').find('.comments_div').hide();
        $(this).find('.comments_div').show('slide');
    });
});
```

Another option is to list the articles, then the comments list after that.

```
<div class="article"> myarticle stuff
   <div class="comments_more">Read comments...</div>
</div>
<div class="article"> new stuff
   <div class="comments_more">Read comments...</div>
</div>
<div class="allcomments">
    <div class="comments">
      . . . the comments 
    </div>
    <div class="comments">
      . . . the other comments 
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comments_more').on('click',function() {
        // index of the "article" clicked
        var selectedIndex = $(this).index();
        $('.comments').hide().eq(selectedIndex).show('slide');
    });
});
```